# How to remove try/catch repetitions in class methods?

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I have RESTeasy service. And have implemented simple error handling on methods using `try catch` and feel something is not very well with it. I've noticed try catch repetition on all my methods. So I want ask way how to avoid repetition (to reduce code size) of `try catch` but not lost functionality.

```
@Path("/rest")
@Logged
@Produces("application/json")
public class CounterRestService {

  @POST
  @Path("/create")
  public CounterResponce create(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    try {
        CounterService.getInstance().put(name);
        return new CounterResponce();
    } catch (Exception e){
        return new CounterResponce("error", e.getMessage());
    }   
}

@POST
@Path("/insert")
public CounterResponce create(Counter counter) {
    try {
        CounterService.getInstance().put(counter);
        return new CounterResponce();
    } catch (Exception e){
        return new CounterResponce("error", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@DELETE
@Path("/delete")
public CounterResponce delete(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    try {
        CounterService.getInstance().remove(name);
        return new CounterResponce();
    } catch (Exception e){
        return new CounterResponce("error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
... // other methods with some try catch pattern
```

response

```
public class CounterResponce {
private String status;

@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL)
private Object data;

public CounterResponce() {
    this.status = "ok";
}

public CounterResponce(Object o) {
    this.status = "ok";
    this.data = o;
}

public CounterResponce(String status, Object o){
    this.status = status;
    this.data = o;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public Object getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

exceptions source

```
public class CounterService {

private Map<String, StatisticCounter> counters = new HashMap<String, StatisticCounter>();

private static CounterService instance = null;

protected CounterService() {}

public static CounterService getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new CounterService();
      }
      return instance;
}

public StatisticCounter get(String name){
    StatisticCounter c =  counters.get(name);
    if(c == null)throw new IllegalArgumentException("Counter "+name+" not exist");
    return c;
}

public void put(String name){
    if(name==null)throw new IllegalArgumentException("null can`t be as name");
    if(counters.get(name)!=null)throw new IllegalArgumentException("Counter "+name+" exist");
    counters.put(name, new Counter(name));
 }...
```

Comment: I don't think you need try catch because there is not likely to be an exception with the code that you are `try`ing

Comment: My exceptions throws from CounterService, added to post

Comment: [this might help](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6653)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking

Comment: Related question in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330539/dry-with-different-try-statements-and-identical-catch-statements

Comment: I'm not familiar with RESTeasy but surely it has some kind of pluggable exception handler. A quick google search revealed [this](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in your question are pointing you in a good direction. Since the answers do not mention it, I'll summarize the general idea in this answer.

### Extending `WebApplicationException`

JAX-RS allows to define direct mapping of Java exceptions to HTTP error responses. By extending [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), you can create application specific exceptions that build a HTTP response with the status code and an optional message as the body of the response.

The following exception builds a HTTP response with the [`404`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) status code:

```
public class CustomerNotFoundException extends WebApplicationException {

    /**
    * Create a HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
    */
    public CustomerNotFoundException() {
      super(Responses.notFound().build());
    }

    /**
    * Create a HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
    * @param message the String that is the entity of the 404 response.
    */
    public CustomerNotFoundException(String message) {
      super(Response.status(Responses.NOT_FOUND).
      entity(message).type("text/plain").build());
    }
}
```

[`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and doesn't need to the wrapped in a `try`-`catch` block or be declared in a `throws` clause:

```
@Path("customers/{customerId}")
public Customer findCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {
    Customer customer = customerService.find(customerId);
    if (customer == null) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer not found with ID " + customerId);
    }
    return customer;
}
```

### Creating `ExceptionMapper`s

In other cases it may not be appropriate to throw instances of [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), or classes that extend [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), and instead it may be preferable to map an existing exception to a response.

For such cases it is possible to use a custom exception mapping provider. The provider must implement the [`ExceptionMapper<E extends Throwable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) interface. For example, the following maps the JAP [`EntityNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) to a HTTP [`404`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) response:

```
@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper 
    implements ExceptionMapper<EntityNotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EntityNotFoundException ex) {
      return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

When an [`EntityNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) is thrown, the [`toResponse(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html#toResponse-E-) method of the `EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper` instance will be invoked.

The [`@Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation declares that the class is of interest to the JAX-RS runtime. Such class may be added to the set of classes of the [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) instance that is configured.

Answer (score 1):

1. Introduce a private method such as "apply" which can take function as parameter if you use Java 8. This method will have the error handling and/or mapping, response mapping and response generation code centralized.
2. From create and delete methods, invoke this apply method and pass the desired counter operation you wish to perform as a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks sounds good, but I use Java 7, so I can`t use function as parameter. On the other hand, is good time to start use it :)