# Handling errors in REST webservices with Java

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST service with a method anotated with `@Produces("application/pdf")`.

If an exception occurres on server side, our logic throws custom exception which extends `RuntimeException` and I have:

```
throw new CustomerException(new CustomProblem("something wrong"));
```

What is a best way to return something to the client, who in this case see:

```
Status: 500
Body: No message body writer has been found for response class CustomProblem.
```

Answer (score 2):

Previously, I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227).

Basically, you can adopt one of the following approaches to handle your exceptions (extracted from [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6653) but also applies to RESTEasy or other JAX-RS 2.0 implementations):

### Extending `WebApplicationException`

JAX-RS allows to define direct mapping of Java exceptions to HTTP error responses. By extending [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), you can create application specific exceptions that build a HTTP response with the status code and an optional message as the body of the response.

The following exception builds a HTTP response with the [`404`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) status code:

```
public class CustomerNotFoundException extends WebApplicationException {

    /**
    * Create a HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
    */
    public CustomerNotFoundException() {
      super(Responses.notFound().build());
    }

    /**
    * Create a HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
    * @param message the String that is the entity of the 404 response.
    */
    public CustomerNotFoundException(String message) {
      super(Response.status(Responses.NOT_FOUND).
      entity(message).type("text/plain").build());
    }
}
```

[`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and doesn't need to the wrapped in a `try`-`catch` block or be declared in a `throws` clause:

```
@Path("customers/{customerId}")
public Customer findCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {

    Customer customer = customerService.find(customerId);
    if (customer == null) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer not found with ID " + customerId);
    }
    return customer;
}
```

### Creating `ExceptionMapper`s

In other cases it may not be appropriate to throw instances of [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), or classes that extend [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), and instead it may be preferable to map an existing exception to a response.

For such cases it is possible to use a custom exception mapping provider. The provider must implement the [`ExceptionMapper<E extends Throwable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) interface. For example, the following maps the JAP [`EntityNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) to a HTTP [`404`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) response:

```
@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper 
    implements ExceptionMapper<EntityNotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EntityNotFoundException ex) {
      return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

When an [`EntityNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) is thrown, the [`toResponse(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html#toResponse-E-) method of the `EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper` instance will be invoked.

The [`@Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation declares that the class is of interest to the JAX-RS runtime. Such class may be added to the set of classes of the [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) instance that is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Implement https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html and put the annotation @Provider to that. Override the toResponse() method and return a Response which is JSON or something meaningful. You can also use @Context to obtain the header passed in the request.