# ResponseBuilder is not working when used with entity object

Tags: java, jax-rs, response

I am trying to create a response with responsebuilder.
When I pass string in entity it works fine but when I pass some error class it doesnot works.

Here is code

1) Working fine

```
Response.status(400).entity("test").build();
```

2) Not working

```
Response.status(400).entity(new MyCustomExceptions(400,"My bad request")).build();
```

With above code I am getting error

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain
```

when I call this service with above code I am getting 500 error instead of 400.But in 1st case I am getting proper 400 error.

- Just wanted to understand if I pass object to entity then do I need
  to override some methods in class MyCustomExceptions?
- How response is created from MyCustomExceptions object?
- If I pass string to entity it works fine.Why?

Comment: Could you try `Response.status(400).entity(new MyCustomExceptions(400,"My bad request")).type("text/plain").build();` let me know the status.

Comment: Adding type("text/plain") is returning with same error.

Comment: Actually you return an entity, so rather you should use a application/json or application/xml, depending on what transformer you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mapping exceptions to HTTP error responses

JAX-RS allows you to define a direct mapping of Java exceptions to HTTP error responses.

By extending [`WebApplicationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227), you can create application specific exceptions that build a HTTP response with the status code and an optional message as the body of the response.

With that in mind, instead of returning a [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), you could throw a [`BadRequestException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html) which extends [`WebApplicationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227) and will be mapped to a HTTP response with the status code [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1):

```java
throw new BadRequestException("My bad request");
```

For more details regarding error handling in JAX-RS, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227).

### Subclasses of `WebApplicationException`

For convenience, the [`WebApplicationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227) is currently extended by the following exceptions (and they can be extended to create your own exceptions):

- [`RedirectionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/RedirectionException.html): [`3xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) status codes for *Redirection* errors
- [`ClientErrorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ClientErrorException.html): [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) status codes for *Client* errors

  - [`BadRequestException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html): [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) Bad Request
  - [`ForbiddenException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ForbiddenException.html): [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) Forbidden
  - [`NotAcceptableException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotAcceptableException.html): [`406`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) Not Acceptable
  - [`NotAllowedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotAllowedException.html): [`405`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) Method Not Allowed
  - [`NotAuthorizedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotAuthorizedException.html): [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) Unauthorized
  - [`NotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html): [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) Not Found
  - [`NotSupportedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotSupportedException.html): [`415`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) Unsupported Media Type
- [`ServerErrorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/RedirectionException.html): [`5xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) status codes for *Server* errors

  - [`InternalServerErrorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/InternalServerErrorException.html): [`500`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) Internal Server Error
  - [`ServiceUnavailableException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ServiceUnavailableException.html): [`503`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) Service Unavailable

Comment: I tried and it works but not able to understand as how throwing an exception returns a Response object. Any pointers will hellp.

Comment: @Alien01 It's made by the JAX-RS runtime. I will add more details to my answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `accept` parameter in HTTPHeader that you're passing? Looks like its `text/plain` and you're trying to return an Object.

1. Pass the `accept` value as `application/json` in the request. OR
2. Change your code in response to add type as `Json/XML`

   ```
   Response.status(400).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(new MyCustomExceptions(400,"My bad request")).build();
   ```

Comment: I changed to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , I did not get any error message but still did not get 400 error code.

Comment: Are you sure? I got the response and with status as 400. Can you show how you're calling the service?