# Default page for unimplemented REST endpoints?

Tags: java, rest

I'm creating a REST service in Java. I use javax package. I have the following question:
is it possible to create something like "default page" for the unimplemented endpoints? I.e., let us suppose I implement the following endpoints:

localhost:8080/rest/a

localhost:8080/rest/b

And know I want some default page to be loaded if a user enters e.g. localhost:8080/rest/c (maybe some redirect for 404 error?). I looked for something like this in Google but with no success. I have no idea what I could start from. Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:**

I would like to mention that I tried to add to my web.xml something like this:

```html
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

but unfortunately I doesn't work for REST addresses (localhost:8080/rest/something). However, it does work for any other addresses.

**EDIT2:**

I put some code snippets:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

}
```

===========================================================

```
@Path("/myview")
public class MyView {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public Response root() throws NotImplementedException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test() throws NotImplementedException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT3:**

@cássio-mazzochi-molin sorry for a delay, I couldn't check this. But now I have checked this and I'm not sure if this is what I want.

I've implemented EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<EntityNotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EntityNotFoundException exception) {
        return Response.status(404).entity(exception.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

and added it to the Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper.class));
    }
}
```

But there is a problem - if I want it to work, I have to define an endpoint, let's say "C" and throw there EntityNotFoundException. But I want it to be thrown for every unimplemented endpoint. I'm afraid there is an infinite number of such cases...

Comment: Could you please share a bit of code? If a resource cannot be found on the server, you should return a response with the `404` status code and a payload describing the error. If you actually want to indicate that something has not been implemented and the request cannot be handled, you should return a response with the `501` status code.

Comment: _I use javax package._ Do you mean JAX-RS and one of its implementations?

Comment: Yes, I use [javax.ws.rs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html)

Comment: I added some code snippets.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327321/1426227).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below method in your controller

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
            return "page not found";
        }
```

and below class to your code:

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException { }
```

Instead of returning page not found string, you can return a page by specifying some model in the method.

Comment: The question is quite broad regarding the framework the OP is using. You shouldn't assume the OP is using Spring.

Comment: I'm not using Spring unfortunately.

Comment: OP is not responding to your question  *Could you please share a bit of code?* He/she is may be thinking that we know about code. so I just assume that he was using something like this . :D peace.. @CássioMazzochiMolin

Answer (score 0):

With JAX-RS, you can define an [`ExceptionMapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to map an exception to a [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html):

```java
@Provider
public class NotImplementedExceptionMapper 
       implements ExceptionMapper<NotImplementedException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        String html = ...
        return Response.status(501).entity(html).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
    }
}
```

For more details on handling errors in JAX-RS, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708222/1426227).

---

Picking the right status code:

- If a resource cannot be found on the server, you should return a response with the [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) status code. It indicates a *client error*.
- If you actually want to indicate that something has not been implemented and the request cannot be handled, you should return a response with the [`501`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.2) status code. It indicates a *server error*.

Comment: Thank you. But as I understand, I have to map this implementation to the defined endpoint, don't I? And I want this code to be executed for EVERY unimplemented endpoint.

Comment: @user2905035 See my updated answer. `ExceptionMapper` is what you are looking for. It allows you to map an exception to a `Response`.